# sql multiple join query and multiple count

Tags: mysql

I want to count (current Day Sale and Monthly Sale AND QUARTER SALE) from my product sell out table, individually all three queries are working fine but i want to clubbed into one.

```
SELECT tm.internal_name AS model_number, tm.item_description, tm.mrp, tm.asin, COUNT( product_serial_no ) AS  `S_FTD` FROM register_product_claim INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin WHERE retailer_code =  '9017' AND register_product_claim.dt =  '2016-08-04' GROUP BY tm.asin ORDER BY register_product_claim.dt DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This is for a particular retailer for the current date

2) This is for the Monthly Sell Out Count

```
SELECT tm.internal_name AS model_number, tm.item_description, tm.mrp, tm.asin, COUNT( product_serial_no ) AS  `S_MTD` FROM register_product_claim INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin WHERE retailer_code =  '9017' AND MONTH( register_product_claim.dt ) =  '08' GROUP BY tm.asin ORDER BY register_product_claim.dt DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

3) This is for the quarter

```
SELECT tm.internal_name AS model_number, tm.item_description, tm.mrp, tm.asin, COUNT( product_serial_no ) AS  `S_QTD` 
FROM register_product_claim INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin WHERE retailer_code =  '9017'
AND ( MONTH( register_product_claim.dt ) =  '08'
OR MONTH( register_product_claim.dt ) =  '07'
OR MONTH( register_product_claim.dt ) =  '06'
) GROUP BY tm.asin ORDER BY register_product_claim.dt DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Desired Output is

```
model_number | item_description  |  mrp  |  asin  |  S_FTD  |  S_MTD | S_QTD
```

Comment: can you post sample date and expect result.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT 
    stat1.model_number model_number,
    stat1.item_description item_description,
    stat1.mrp mrp,
    stat1.asin asin,
    stat1.S_FTD S_FTD,
    stat2.S_MTD S_MTD,
    stat3.S_QTD S_QTD
FROM
    (SELECT 
        tm.internal_name AS model_number,
            tm.item_description,
            tm.mrp,
            tm.asin,
            COUNT(product_serial_no) AS `S_FTD`
    FROM
        register_product_claim
    INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
    WHERE
        retailer_code = '9017'
            AND register_product_claim.dt = '2016-08-04'
    GROUP BY tm.asin
    ORDER BY register_product_claim.dt DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 30) stat1
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        tm.internal_name AS model_number,
            COUNT(product_serial_no) AS `S_MTD`
    FROM
        register_product_claim
    INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
    WHERE
        retailer_code = '9017'
            AND MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '08'
    GROUP BY tm.asin
    ORDER BY register_product_claim.dt DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 30) stat2 ON stat1.model_number = stat2.model_numer
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        tm.internal_name AS model_number,
            COUNT(product_serial_no) AS `S_QTD`
    FROM
        register_product_claim
    INNER JOIN tbl_model tm ON register_product_claim.model_number = tm.asin
    WHERE
        retailer_code = '9017'
            AND (MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '08'
            OR MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '07'
            OR MONTH(register_product_claim.dt) = '06')
    GROUP BY tm.asin
    ORDER BY register_product_claim.dt DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 30) stat3 ON stat1.model_number = stat3.model_number
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, query works one one issue found , for Month wise and quarter wise we have more product list who is being sold out but only two models were displayed and month wise and quarter wise query of approx 5 products

Comment: #Vanojx1 Dear am have tried left join but nothing will happen, same result

Comment: im sorry but without db schema and testing its hard for me... but..... whats the query with more result??

Comment: actually DB schema is too lengthy so could not able to make fiddle , actually my last query QTD one will display total 6 models as a answer but when i combined the query as per your answer it will display the correct records but only with 2 records (as per FTD)